# 'PlaceHolder is not a known element' Warning

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Here's the warning I received when I added `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">` control in one of my .aspx page. I wonder if there'd be any potential problems if I just ignore it.

> Element 'PlaceHolder' is not a known element. This can occur if
>   there's a compilation error in the website, or the web.config file is
>   missing.

I placed `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">` control within `<head></head>` HTML block and the code looked something like below.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
<%
    if (condition == met)
        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + ResolveClientUrl("~/a.js") "'></script>");
    else
        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + ResolveClientUrl("~/b.js") "'></script>");
%>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

So is it safe to ignore the warning? Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks.

Comment: maybe, target framework in your web application project is not ".NET Framework 4". For example: .Net Framework 2.0 or 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285632.aspx), Visual Studio is doing that because you placed the control inside the head. It appears like it is safe to do it that way though.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding id attribute to asp:PlaceHolder tag.

Comment: looks like it's not caused by missing id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the head of the masterpage runat=server and put a contentplaceholder inside the head. In the content page, everything you put into the content corresponding to the content placeholder in the head will render into the head.

Thanks